# Baja Java and Tridium

Tags: java

Hey Im trying to write a program that takes in the day of the week(baja:string) from a calendar and stops an air handler based on the time that is dynamically set (baja:time). It will need to output a time value(baja:time).

If Sunday then stop at 2pm
If Monday then stop at 8pm

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish weekly scheduling for AHUs is with a `BooleanSchedule` or `EnumSchedule` object (depending on whether your occupancy variable is enumerated or boolean).  Both can be found in the "schedule" module.

These schedules (and the similar `NumericSchedule` and `StringSchedule` objects) have a "Scheduler" view that allow you to customize the time at which transitions take place according to day of the week.  For more information on how to effectively use the scheduler view, search for "weekly scheduler view" in the Niagara help.

Normally, you use the output slot of the `EnumSchedule` or `BooleanSchedule` to directly control equipment, but if you are sure you need a `baja:Time` you can manipulate the output from any schedule object to get it.

Extracting the next "off" time will utilize two slots on your new schedule: nextTime and nextValue.  `nextTime` is a `baja:AbsTime` object that always shows the time of the next change of state--whether that new state will be "off" or "on".  `nextValue` gives what the value of the schedule output will be after the next transition.

Assuming you are using Niagara 3.6.x or higher, you can wire the nextTime slot to the input of a `NumericLatch` (from the kitControl palette), and Niagara will automatically convert the `baja:AbsTime` object into a numeric timestamp.  You can then use logic to wire `nextValue` to the "Clock" slot of the latch so it will only update with the next "off" time.  This will update the output of the latch with the timstamp of the next "off" time whenever your weekly schedule is in the  "on" state

Finally, to get `baja:Time` back you need to convert the numeric timestamp back to a time object.  Again, assuming you're using 3.6.x or later, you can use an `Expr` (from the kitControl module) component to do the job:

1. Add an `Expr` to you wire sheet, and open it's slot sheet.
2. Add a slot of type `baja:StatusNumeric` called "timestampIn," and make sure the Summary and Execute On Change flags are checked.
3. Add a slot of type `baja:AbsTime` called "absTimeOut", and make sure Summary and Readonly flags are checked
4. Open the property sheet of the `Expr` object, and type "timestampIn.value as 'absTimeOut' " (without the double quotes) into the Expr property

At this point, you have a custom `Expr` that will convert numeric inputs into `baja:AbsTime`.  Wire it to the output of your latch and you've got a `baja:AbsTime` of the next scheduled active time for your weekly schedule.

`baja:Time` and `baja:AbsTime` are not the exact same thing, but `AbsTime` implements all the functions in `baja:Time`.  However, if you absolutely need `baja:Time`, you can add another slot to your `Expr` component of type baja:Time, then add a second line to the expression to convert the `baja:AbsTime` to `baja:Time` (you can't go directly to `baja:Time` because the numeric time stores both date and time information and won't convert to `baja:Time` correctly).  Put a comma at the end of the first line, than add a line that reads

```
absTimeOut as 'timeOut'
```